# java files missing in scr folder in each Activity (eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Details: **I have reinstalled eclipse 3 times, updated it & the ADT and DDMS, too**.

I have found out that when I create a new android project the scr file is nearly empty. In each Activity there is only one java file and the rest is missing. I have attached a screenshot from the Maste/Detail flow activity so that you see where the problem is.

If you can help me please leave a response.

[image]

Comment: I can't see what the problem is at all. What is the problem? And what do you mean that in each Activity there is only one java file? That doesn't even make sense. Why would a java file be 'in' an Activity?

Comment: When you create a new android project (here for example with an Master/Detail flow activity) it should create additional java files, but its only create one or none. I'm following tutorial and I can't continue with that bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug - it might generate additional files 
depending on what starting activity you choose e.g. login activity it requires additional logic for working with Google+, however most will contain all the logic for a specific activity in a single source file, the source code included in the source files will often be minimal to make sure the activity works without the developer having to manually implement things they might otherwise not know about e.g. the fragment activity.

You might want to try out [android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) instead if you are not dependent on eclipse as android seems to be moving towards using it and gradle.

(I do use android studios and am currently working on android apps and even though it's in beta it has not given me any problems)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went over to Android studio and it is much better and eye friendlier than eclipse. It also has fixed my problem.

Comment: This is clearly a bug. The class derived from `Activity`/`FragmentActivity` is not created. When you run the app, the project will fail with `ClassNotFoundException`. The problem is likely in the template files in tools\templates\activities\MasterDetailFlow\root\src\app_package

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug. Refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72571

To solve the problem, look for ftl files in the tools\templates\activities subfolder of the SDK. In the files found, change `<#if appCompat>` to `<#if appCompat?has_content>`, and `${appCompat?string('Fragment','')}` to `${(appCompat?has_content)?string('Fragment','')}`.